# How to check the balance of merchant and customer

Tags: authorize.net

I am very new to Authorize.Net and i am having some difficulty in learning the business domain and logic for the Authorize.Net. I have read the documentation much as I could but did not find the answer of my question that :

Although sandbox provides me the testing environment for the merchant but how i will charge the customer credit card. From where and to where i can get and applied the customer credit cards like the credit card number for test.

Secondly how I will check that this amount is remaining in that credit card and where to check the account earnings or test money it is getting from charging that credit cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From where and to where i can get and applied the customer credit cards like the credit card number for test.

You can get test credit card numbers and information about testing using Authorize.Net from their [testing guide](https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/).

> How i will check that this amount is remaining in that credit card and where to check the account earnings or test money it is getting from charging that credit cards.

You can't. This information is not available through their API or any other API you can have access to.

Comment: Thank you i was not finding that link rather i was pondering on get started guide. Secondly how i will know that the amount has been deducted from customer and added to the merchant. even i cannot check my balance which is deducted from customers?

Comment: You don't need to check that the amount is transferred as part of your application. It just *happens*. You could check your bank account to see when the funds are deposited, which is typically 1-3 business days depending on the bank and the credit card used, but that is something you need to do manually.

Comment: actually i am talking about the sandbox account. if it is possible to view the amount in my account

Comment: Well, there is no amount in your account because Authorize.Net does not keep any of the funds of the transactions. They go straight to your bank account from the merchant account provider. Since both of these are fake you can't actually see any funds. You can see a transaction history in the control panel for your test account or through the reporting API. But test accounts are fake so their is no place to go to see any funds from credit cards you processed.

Comment: i know i dont want really the money ;). I just asking for the sake of testing and demonstration purpose.

Comment: The testing part the test account is good for. The demonstration part it only will allow you to show how an integration will work. It won't be able to show you money flowing through the system. You would need to go live and then make a test transaction with a real credit card account.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my basic question much help provided. Cheers!

Comment: just a last question did i have to specify the card type like master or visa card?

Comment: Nope. All of the system handling the credit card know what type it is and what to do with it.